# Try-except with three possibilities in json path

Tags: json, python-3.x, try-catch

I've got some json with slightly different paths, like the first:

```
dcSubject:
    fre:
         0: Marie(Sainte)
         1: Anges
```

and the second:

```
   dcSubject:
        en:
             0: Railroads--Ireland
```

and a third with no dcSubject at all. 
So I want to `try` if there is the path element["dcSubject"]["en"] or element["dcSubject"]["fre"] and assign it to a value, or, if there isn't any of that, assign an empty value.
I tried:

```
try:
    subjects = element["dcSubject"]["en"]
except:
    subjects = element["dcSubject"]["fre"]
else:
    subjects = ""
```

but it obviously doesn't work because it prints an empty subject if the "en" path is right. Then I tried (just for fun)

```
try:
    subjects = element["dcSubject"]["en"] or element["dcSubject"]["fre"]
except:
    subjects = ""
```

But it's not correct.

Is it possible to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `.get()` method. It defaults to `None` if the key doesn't exist

```
subjects = ""

if element["dcSubject"].get("en"):
    subjects = element["dcSubject"]["en"]
elif element["dcSubject"].get("fr"):
    subjects = element["dcSubject"]["fr"]
```

This won't raise a `KeyError` if "en" or "fr" don't exist and will skip the code block if they are just an empty array

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should go in this direction to use recursive function to find value for desired key in nested json (if key doesnt exist you will get empty list, if key exist function 
will return a value for the associated key):

```
element = {"dcSubject":{"fre":{"0": "Marie","1": "Anges"}}}

def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x

if list(findkeys(element,'en')) != []:
    subjects = list(findkeys(element,'en'))
elif list(findkeys(element,'fre')) != []:
    subjects = list(findkeys(element,'fre'))
else:
    subjects = ""

print (subjects)
```

Comment: That's a little bit too much complicated, since I have lots of other metadata to check. But thanks anyway